# Error: operation not permited

Tags: pthreads

I tried to test the first example of following page in C language, to recognize how exactly mutex works within the pthread creation. But unfortunately I got the problem that "operation not permitted". Can somebody tell me what's wrong with those codes? I even tested the other examples but I have same errors.

[Here](https://writer.zoho.com/public/rreginelli/Chapter-8---Mutexes-and-Concurrency-R21/noband)'s the page link

```
my output:     t1: waiting on mutex
               t1: waiting on mutex
               Error creating thread 1: Operation not permitted
```

I run this sample in Eclipse on Ubuntu/linaro 4.6.3 
Thank you in advanced

Comment: It works fine on my machine...can you tell me how you compiled the code?

Comment: well,as I told I wrote the code in eclips.so I just run the code in eclips to get the result.

Comment: try on system terminal --  gcc $prog_name -lpthread

Comment: It has also same error.please help me.I am new in linux and working with pthread,so I can not exactly understand that ,is there a system error or sth related to codes.I tested these codes also in other system with  linux fedora but has same error.

Answer (score 0):

why are you setting priority of threads? Just disable these below lines

```
//schedp.sched_priority = priority;
```

and

```
// if ret = 0
// ret = pthread_setschedparam(*thread, SCHED_FIFO, &schedp);
```

It will work fine on linux machine too after disabling above lines. I have tested it.

I don't think so you need to set priority of these threads.